# pytorch embedding index out of range

Tags: python, neural-network, nlp, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I'm following this tutorial here https://cs230-stanford.github.io/pytorch-nlp.html. In there a neural model is created, using `nn.Module`, with an embedding layer, which is initialized here

```
self.embedding = nn.Embedding(params['vocab_size'], params['embedding_dim'])
```

`vocab_size` is the total number of training samples, which is 4000.  `embedding_dim` is 50.  The relevant piece of the `forward` method is below

```
def forward(self, s):
        # apply the embedding layer that maps each token to its embedding
        s = self.embedding(s)   # dim: batch_size x batch_max_len x embedding_dim
```

I get this exception when passing a batch to the model like so
`model(train_batch)`
`train_batch` is a numpy array of dimension `batch_size`x`batch_max_len`.  Each sample is a sentence, and each sentence is padded so that it has the length of the longest sentence in the batch.

> File
>   "/Users/liam_adams/Documents/cs512/research_project/custom/model.py",
>   line 34, in forward
>       s = self.embedding(s)   # dim: batch_size x batch_max_len x embedding_dim   File
>   "/Users/liam_adams/Documents/cs512/venv_research/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py",
>   line 493, in **call**
>       result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)   File "/Users/liam_adams/Documents/cs512/venv_research/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/sparse.py",
>   line 117, in forward
>       self.norm_type, self.scale_grad_by_freq, self.sparse)   File "/Users/liam_adams/Documents/cs512/venv_research/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py",
>   line 1506, in embedding
>       return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse) RuntimeError: index out of range at
>   ../aten/src/TH/generic/THTensorEvenMoreMath.cpp:193

Is the problem here that the embedding is initialized with different dimensions than those of my batch array?  My `batch_size` will be constant but `batch_max_len` will change with every batch. This is how its done in the tutorial.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the answer here https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/embeddings-index-out-of-range-error/12582

I'm converting words to indexes, but I had the indexes based off the total number of words, not `vocab_size` which is a smaller set of the most frequent words.

Answer (score 3):

You've got some things wrong. Please correct those and re-run your code:

- `params['vocab_size']` is the total number of unique tokens. So, it should be `len(vocab)` in the tutorial.
- `params['embedding_dim']` can be `50` or `100` or whatever you choose. Most folks would use something in the range `[50, 1000]` both extremes inclusive. Both Word2Vec and GloVe uses `300` dimensional embeddings for the words.
- `self.embedding()` would accept arbitrary batch size. So, it doesn't matter. BTW, in the tutorial the commented things such as `# dim: batch_size x batch_max_len x embedding_dim` indicates the shape of output tensor of that specific operation, not the inputs.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was with my word indexes being greater than my `vocab_size`

Comment: I'm running into the same problem, but I didn't change the dictionary at all. How that your word indexes is bigger than the vocab size?

Answer (score 0):

embedding size in `nn.embedding` should be `max(input_data)`. check your datatypes of the input_data, as this have to be integer for deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tokenizer from huggingface transformers this is how you will set up your embedding.

The torch.nn.Embedding accepts two mandatory parameters, [Pytorch Documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Embedding.html)

1. num_embeddings
2. embedding_dim

your *num_embeddings* is the *vocab size* associated with your tokenizer and your *embedding_dim* can be the *max sequence length* (or anything you like, try not to unnecessarily use values that are too big)

So you define your embedding as follows.

```
embedding = torch.nn.Embedding(num_embeddings=tokenizer.vocab_size, 
                               embedding_dim=embedding_dim)
output = embedding(input)
```

Note that you may add additional parameters as per your requirement and adjust the embedding dimension to your needs.